# on off switch- Add or remove layer

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I need to remove my layer. My code is adding layer again and again instead of removing.

This is my check box.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">Boundary<input type="checkbox" id="layer1" onclick="firstlayer()"></label>
```

and this is my js part

```
layer1.onclick = function () {
  
  var boundary = new TileLayer({
    source: new TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'HGMUAE:boundary', 'TILED': true},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
      transition: 0,
    }),
  })
  
  map.addLayer(boundary)
  
};



function firstlayer() {
    if (document.getElementById("layer1").checked) {
        boundary.setVisibility(true);
    } else {
        boundary.setVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

What to do?
I need on off Switch.
Please Guide thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should include more infos about what `TileLayer` is and what it returns

Comment: `boundary` is a local variable in an anonymous click handler function. The value of the variable (the tile) needs to be available in `firstLayer`. Do you need help on how to do that?

Comment: Yes please... Actually i am trying to remove the layer when i unchecked the button

Answer (score 0):

I assume `layer1` in JavaScript is the input element with id "layer1". Setting its `onclick` property to an anonymous function replaces the `onclick` handler defined in HTML, so repeated clicking creates a new tile.

To resolve the sequence of click actions, the algorithm design could resemble:

```
click: if( layer has not been created)
            create layer
            store layer object (in variable boundary)
            add to map
            record that its visible (in checkbox value)
       else if (layer is visible)
            delete/remove from map
            record that is not visible
       else ( layer has been created and is not visible)
            add layer in variable boundary to map
            record that it is visible.
```

Although most of this could be written as a single function there are several assumptions and issues that should be looked at before coding:

- is there a function to remove a tile from the map?
- is the third click action supposed to re-install a tile in the map without recreating it?
- would the "change" event be better than "click" when using checkboxes?
- can reloading the page set the checkbox to the value it had before reload? (e.g. in Firefox would you need to explicitly reset a form or form elements on page load?)

I suggest mocking up some code to get the sequence of events working using, say, "click" events and see if it could be changed, or needs to be changed to use "change" events in production.

Some concept code which may help explain the idea better:

```
function firstLayer(event) {
    var boundary = new Tile ( /* arguments */);
    map.addLayer(boundary);
    var visible = true; // this.checked should be the same

    this.onclick = function() {
        if( visible) {
             map.removeLayer( boundary);
        }
        else {
             map.addLayer( boundary);
        }
     };
}
```